# CSS selector to target list-item containing the nested list

Tags: css-selectors

In this HTML:

```html
<ol>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four
    <ol>
      <li>Us</li>
      <li>They
        <ol>
          <li>Monkey</li>
          <li>Cat</li>
          <li>Elephant</li>
          <li>Dos</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li>You</li>
      <li>She</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

how do I target those list-items that contain the nested list? In this particular example, how do I target the list-items with the words “Four” and “They”?

Since the html will change constantly, I am looking for an option that do not depend on classes or other method that require me to alter the html in order to stylize it.

**It is possible to target theses list-items without touching the HTML?** It seems to me that it might be hard/impossible since there is no a CSS parent selector. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

It's not that hard you just have to add an id to the specific item in the list or a class to the group of items in the list it depends on what you want to modify.
Example:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
      <ol class = "list">

        <li id = "one">One</li>
        <li id = "two">Two</li>
        <li id = "three">Three</li>
        <li id = "four">Four</li>

      </ol>

  </body>
</html>
```

Now in your css file you just have to targe what you want to give style. If its an id you have tou use a "." and the name of the id like: ".one" or if its a class you have tu use the "#" like this: "#list"

Comment: Thanks, but as I say in the question: “Since the html will change constantly, I am looking for an option that do not depend on classes or other method that require me to alter the html in order to stylize it.”